# Git cherry pick a commit and place it below

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

From what I know, by default the `cherry-pick` command takes a commit and places it on top of the current branch.
Is it possible to `cherry-pick` a commit in Git and place it below the current commit?

Answer (score 18):

You can always perform a `rebase` after the cherry-pick. So it would look something like that:

```
git cherry-pick <hash>
git rebase HEAD~2 -i
```

Swap the commit orders in the rebase window.

**Second Option**

In case you want to solve conflicts only once, as you stated. You can take the long way.
Remove the current commit, cherry pick the other one, and then cherry-pick the latest commit.

```
git log --oneline -1
  <write_down_this_hash> description
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git cherry-pick <hash to cherry pick>
git cherry-pick <write_down_this_hash>
```

Comment: the problem is that, after the cherry pick, I enter the "conflict resolution" phase. I would like to solve the conflicts just once, when the cherry-picked commit is not on top (but in the right place just below the top).

Comment: I provided a second (longer) option in the answer.

Comment: @nyarlathotep108: You might want to consider trying `git rerere`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another approach. Let's say your history looks like this:

```
A - B - D master, HEAD
    \
     C other
```

and you want to [cherry pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) commit `C` *before* `HEAD` so that the resulting history becomes:

```
A - B - C' - D' master, HEAD
    \
     C other
```

Then you can do:

1. `git checkout HEAD^` to move `HEAD` to commit `B`
2. `git cherry-pick other master` to apply commits `C` and `D` on top of `B`
3. `git branch -f master HEAD` to make `master` point to the same commit as `HEAD`
4. `git checkout master` to move `HEAD` to `master`

Comment: This is how I would do it myself.  (Though I'd call the resulting final commit `D'` since it will be a copy of `D` rather than the original `D`.)

Comment: True, the resulting `D` will have a different SHA-1 than the original one, but since there's only one `D` in the second graph it isn't necessary to annotate it with prime. However, I do see your point if one were to compare the two graphs with each other.